# Stop socket.io from complaining in the browser when the server is down

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm experimenting with socket.io.

Scenario:

I have several tabs open that are initially connected to the server. I stop the server because I want to do some work on the code. The browsers start logging:

```js
polling-xhr.js:206 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NhdlRB- net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Is there any way to suppress this error? It's using a lot of system resources in each browser tab when it happens, especially if the browser is running in that state for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can `socket.disconnect()`; on error, otherwise it will try to reconnect.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work, but it should. Looking at like 206 of polling-xhr.js, there is a catch below, but it never fires. It looks like a bug in socket.io. The xhr request should be in a try/catch block of its own.

Comment: Ok, so there must be `socket.io.on("error", (error) => {})`, you can also try `socket.io.on("reconnect_error", (error) => {})`, but I would use `socket.io.on("reconnect_attempt", (attempt) => {})` and disconnect if the amount of attemts is more than x

Comment: Yeah, the bug I described in polling-xhr.js never fires an error event because the xhr request doesn't have a try/catch block to catch the error. Both of your other suggestions are working perfectly. Thank you